# Adding outputs into list PYTHON

Tags: python, list

Currently a beginner when it comes to coding.

I am currently trying to make a dice-rolling simulator where the program allows the user to roll a specific number of times before it terminates.

Question is, how do I add the randomly generated numbers from my function into my list? After letting the user roll a couple times and I type "stat", the output list shows [None, None]

Below is the list of what I currently have. Thank you.

```
import random

rolled_numbers = []
i = 1

while True:
    dice_roll = input("Do you want to roll a dice? ")

    if dice_roll == "yes":
        dice_roll_result = print(random.randint(1, 6))  # print a random number from 0 to 9)
        rolled_numbers.append(dice_roll_result)

        i = i + 1
        if i <= 5: # Limits the user to roll 5 times MAX
            continue
        else:  # After 5 tries is rthe eached, program terminates
            break

    elif dice_roll == "no":
        print("Have a wonderful day. Come back to play again!")

    if dice_roll == "stat":
        print(rolled_numbers)
        dice_roll
```

Trying to make the program store outputs from dice_roll_result into the rolled_number list. Not sure if there is another function that is required?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are assigning to `dice_roll_result` the result of calling the `print` function, which will print your number but does not actually return it.

What you actually want to do is first save the number itself to your variable, then print the variable:

```py
dice_roll_result = random.randint(1, 6) # generate a random number from 1 to 6
print(dice_roll_result) # print the generated number
rolled_numbers.append(dice_roll_result) # save the generated number to a list
```